# Process of Adding Classifier in MOA what is recompile it by adding a jar or java file?

Tags: java, command-line, weka, data-mining, moa

I am trying only adding the .java file using cmd line, by compiling using javac and then executing using command line MOA (Massive Online Analysis).
But it shows error as exception in thread main java.lang.noclassdeffounferror:moa/gui/GUI, so what I basically require is that somebody shows me how to add a classifier, how you guys do it, step by step process only, I don't understand adding of code, because i want only the process not the code.
PLZ HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have WEKA's JAR file you can call to classifiers from your code including the JAR file in your classpath.

Here is an example: http://blog.irodata.com/2011/02/embedding-weka-in-java-application.html

Comment: i want by MOA.jar ...not by WEKA.jar plz help the error java.lang.noclassdeffounferror:moa.gui.GUI